# Bostitch BT 1855 nail gun doesn't drive nails

Tags: powertools

I have a jam on my Bostitch 18 gauge finish nailer.  It basically fires air. Plunger is not retracting NOR extending.

I removed the cap on top and added some oil but looks like the trigger is not pulling the plunger.  You can see in this [30 second video](https://youtu.be/2KmxM5GEVCE) what the problem is.

If anyone’s had this problem or any suggestions please let me know.

[image]

Comment: You may have faulty seals or broken parts. There are some good rebuild options under Support at https://www.bostitch.com/products/tools/construction-tools/nailers/finish-and-brad-nailers/18-gauge-brad-nailer-kit/bt1855k.

Comment: Don’t press the safety with your finger! There is probably a small piece of metal stuck and jamming the gun this happens every so often with all the brands of guns I have you may need to disassemble a bit further. Once I can make the striker pin cycle by hand with a screwdriver it will usually cycle after that. That is if I have brads in the gun, one gun won’t fire without a brad and dirt & metal keep them from hitting the safety or 2 groups that have wedged and prevent the gun from firing.